# React - problem with appearing the bootstrap modal

Tags: reactjs

I've got a tree structure. When I will click right click on the node there is appear contextMenu where I can choose options - "Add Node" and "Edit Node". When I click add node should appear bootstrap modal but it does not appear because on the body I have a click event listener which is responsible for hiding my context menu.

Here are my click listeners methods:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        document.body.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this))
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this))
    }
```

I decided to pass my unmount method to ContextMenu component and call it before show the modal

```
<ContextMenu removeEventListener={this.componentWillUnmount.bind(this)} left={this.state.left} top={this.state.top}/>}
```

ContextMenu:

```
import React from 'react'
import {MyVerticallyCenteredModal} from './MyVerticallyCenteredModal'

function ContextMenu({removeEventListener, left, top}){

    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = React.useState(false);

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <ul className="contextMenu" style={{left: left, top: top}}>
                <li onClick={() => {
                    removeEventListener()
                    setModalShow(true)
                }}>Add Node</li>
                <li>Edit Node</li>
            </ul>

            <MyVerticallyCenteredModal 
                show={modalShow}
                onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}/>
        </React.Fragment>

    )
}

export default ContextMenu
```

And unfortunately, it doesn't work :(

UPDATE:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {treeActions} from '../_actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Node from './Node/Node'
import './style.css'
import ContextMenu from './ContextMenu'

class TreePage extends Component {


    componentDidMount() {
        //this.props.getTree()
        document.body.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this))
    }

    state = {activeNode: 0, showContextMenu: false, top:0, left:0}

    setActiveNode(id) {
        this.setState({activeNode: id})
    }
    handleClick() {
        this.setState({showContextMenu: false})
    }
    handleContextMenu(event, id){
        event.preventDefault()

        this.setActiveNode(id)
        this.setState({showContextMenu: true, left: event.clientX, top: event.clientY})

    }

    renderSubNodes(subNodes) {
        const {activeNode} = this.state
        return (
          <ul>
            {subNodes.map((node) => (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <li>
                        <div onContextMenu={(event) => this.handleContextMenu(event, node.id)} className={activeNode===node.id?"bgSelected":""} key={node.id} onClick={() => this.setActiveNode(node.id)}>
                            <Node name={node.name}/>
                        </div>
                        {node.subNodes.length > 0 && this.renderSubNodes(node.subNodes)}
                    </li>

                </React.Fragment>

            ))}
          </ul>
        );
      }

    render() {
        //const {items} = this.props.tree;
        const tree = [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: 'node1',
              subNodes: [
                {
                    id: 4,
                  name: 'node1-1',
                  subNodes: [],
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                  name: 'node1-2',
                  subNodes: [],
                },
              ],
            },
            {
                id: 2,
              name: 'node2',
              subNodes: [],
            },
            {
                id: 3,
              name: 'node3',
              subNodes: [
                {
                    id: 6,
                  name: 'node3-1',
                  subNodes: [
                    {
                        id: 7,
                      name: 'node3-1-1',
                      subNodes: [],
                    },
                    {
                        id: 8,
                      name: 'node3-1-2',
                      subNodes: [],
                    },
                  ],
                },
                {
                    id: 9,
                  name: 'node3-2',
                  subNodes: [],
                }
              ],
            },
          ];

        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                {this.renderSubNodes(tree)}
                {this.state.showContextMenu? <ContextMenu left={this.state.left} top={this.state.top}/>:''}

            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
function mapState(state){


    return state;
}
const actionCreators = {
    getTree: treeActions.getTree
}

const connectedApp = connect(mapState, actionCreators)(TreePage)
export {connectedApp as TreePage}
```

ContextMenu:

```
import React from 'react'
import {MyVerticallyCenteredModal} from './MyVerticallyCenteredModal'

function ContextMenu({left, top}){

    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = React.useState(false);

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <ul className="contextMenu" style={{left: left, top: top}}>
                <li onClick={(event) => {
                    event.stopPropagation()
                    setModalShow(true)
                }}>Add Node</li>
                <li>Edit Node</li>
            </ul>

            <MyVerticallyCenteredModal 
                show={modalShow}
                onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}/>
        </React.Fragment>

    )
}

export default ContextMenu
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML DOM API has this concept called "event bubbling". In very simple terms, when a node is clicked. The event bubbles al the way up the parent tree. This is causing the onClick on your body to be triggered.

There is a way to stop this behavior, with `event.stopPropagation()`. This will stop the event from bubbling up.

An example in your case would be changing the onClick function to:

```
(event) => {
    event.stopPropagation()
    setModalShow(true)
}
```

This way you won't have to unmount the event handler on the body node.

Comment: I updated my code, but still, I do something wrong. Changes I added in my post.

Comment: Hmm it's hard to find a solution from just this. I suggest trying to see if the onClick is getting called or not. Using breakpoints in browser devtools or console.log statements.

Comment: onClick is not calling